Filter on two columns in Power BI
My data has four columns.
I want to apply a slicer on product and select a product and it should list out all the records with transactions which contain that product.
For example, if I select bananas, it should list out all the records where transaction = 1 and 3.

Create a separate table for fruits. In that table, Banana will have 2 rows with value 1 and 3 in the transaction column. Now, create relation between your new and existing table using Transaction column. Create the Slicer with the Fruit column from new table. This should work.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?
